# How to lower the volume of music in swift?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, xcode6

I am creating a SpriteKit Game with background music looping. The problem is that the music is too loud. How do I lower the volume?

Here is the code I used to set up the music

```
    var backGroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer()
    var bgMusicUrl:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BackGround", withExtension: "wav")
    backGroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:bgMusicUrl, error: nil)
    backGroundMusic.numberOfLoops = (-1)
    backGroundMusic.prepareToPlay()
    backGroundMusic.play()
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
backGroundMusic.volume = 0.5
```

Volume goes from 0.0 to 1.0 (full volume). https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried this, but whatever I do, its always on max volume. Even with the value 0.1. Not sure what to do :s

Comment: @Mr.Boon seems I don't have this problem.

Comment: @Mr.Boon make sure you set the volume after play()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
backGroundMusic.setVolume(0.05, fadeDuration: TimeInterval(1))
```